# GeoJSON file with all the capitals

Tags: javascript, geojson, coordinates, json

I am looking for a GeoJSON file with all the capitals in this format:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          37.628173828125,
          55.7642131648377
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In addition, look at these data : https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-populated-places/, extract capitals and convert it into JSON format.

Comment: You can convert them with mapshaper.org easily by drag the ne_10m_populated_places.dbf, ne_10m_populated_places.prj and ne_10m_populated_places.shp into the upload-area ("Drop files here or select from folder")

Answer (score -1):

Found something similar on github, hope it helps: https://gist.github.com/mcwhittemore/1f81416ff74dd64decc6?short_path=5c9378f#file-usa-state-capitals-geojson-L4